# Multipart Config max file size not working in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, post, mime-types, tomcat8

I have a POST API which consumer `multipart/form-data` data.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postEvent(@HeaderParam("id") String id, 
        @HeaderParam ("schema-version") String schemaVersion,
        byte[] serializedEvents)
```

I wanted to limit the maximum uploaded file size to 64 KB.

So, I made the following change in `webapps\<appName>\WEB-INF\web.xml`

```
<multipart-config>
  <max-file-size>65536</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>65536</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

But it does not seem to be working. I also tried changing the maxPostSize parameter of Connector, though, I know that will work only for case where I am consuming the body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I am using Tomcat 8.0 and Jersey as Rest implementation. Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong here?

Edit: Here is the screenshot of the request:

[image]

And, here is the part of `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>65536</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>65536</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wish to change this parameter for the manager application and not for your own?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the correct path of web.xml that has been changed.

Comment: Do you know something about this? Please, help me.